# Generate unique id for paypal cart

Tags: paypal

I am going to use this php shopping which seems to do what I need:

http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/

When check out I will use this method:

Passing the Aggregate Cart Amount to PayPal (paypal website).

In my cart I am saving extra fields which I want to send to seller 
when transaction is completed and ipn script verify the payment is done.
The script will update also the table.

My doubts are releated to how track the buyer transaction. How to generate
a unique id for my transaction to be used for:

1. update the status of all items
2. select all information and send to the buyer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a token function such as

```
$token = md5(date('YmdhisYmdhis').$user->id));
$token = md5($token;
```

This way you have a generated string which is unique to EVERY user WHENEVER he does a new cart

**explenation**
I am taking the date twice and then appending the user id and making an md5 string out of it

if you dont have user use session_id()

Comment: hi. thanks. How to send this field and get back from paypal. What if I don't have a user id?